# How to filter rows if that fit criteria across grouped columns in R

Tags: r

I would like to remove rows which are not above a certain threshold (in this case 0) across all columns in at least one column group.

This is what my data looks like:
Two sample groups (A&B) each with three replicates and each having three observations (metabolites)

```
      metabolites       A1       A2       A3       B1       B2        B3
      1          m1 3.703345 1.417572 3.388284 1.480509 2.612082 0.5997665
      2          m2 0.000000 4.114684 2.659948 1.517864 2.690435 0.3141896
      3          m3 0.000000 1.196729 1.373320 0.000000 3.943517 1.8687265
```

I want to keep rows/metabolites 1 and 2 as they have non zero values across all three replicates for at least one of the two groups, but row three does not have completely non-zero values across the replicates for either column group A or B and therefore I want this row removed from the df.

I tried the below to no avail, as the zeros were just converted to NA's.

```
    # Making the df
    metabolites <- paste0("m", 1:3)
    A1 <- c(rnorm(1, 2, 1), 0, 0)
    A2 <- c(rnorm(3, 2, 1))
    A3 <- c(rnorm(3, 2, 1))
    B1 <- c(rnorm(2, 2, 1), 0)
    B2 <- c(rnorm(3, 2, 1))
    B3 <- c(rnorm(3, 2, 1))

    df <- data.frame(metabolites, A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3)

    # Filter - though it didn't remove metabolites when I went back to wide format
   df_filt <- df_long %>% 
      group_by(group) %>%
      filter(value > 0) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      mutate(group = NULL) %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = samples,values_from = value)


     df_filt




     # A tibble: 3 x 7
     # Groups:   metabolites [3]
      metabolites    A1    A2    A3    B1    B2    B3
       <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
     1 m1           2.26  2.49  2.34  3.37 1.37  2.60 
     2 m2          NA     1.97  3.83  1.06 0.567 2.19 
     3 m3          NA    NA     1.82 NA    3.07  0.255
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, without using any package. Simply use `apply` over rows

```
df[apply(df[, -1], 1, FUN = function(x) {
  !(any(x[1:3] == 0) & any(x[4:6] == 0))}), ]



#metabolites      A1       A2       A3       B1       B2       B3
#1          m1 3.87625 3.412236 1.661957 1.013781 1.040031 1.308915
#2          m2 0.00000 2.750544 1.311194 3.453201 3.109803 1.859520
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `sub` to enable grouping by samples (A, B, etc).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-metabolites) %>% 
  mutate(grp = sub("\\d+$", "", name)) %>% 
  mutate(any_zero = any(value == 0), .by = c(metabolites, grp)) %>% 
  filter(!all(any_zero), .by = metabolites) %>% 
  select(-c(grp, any_zero)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols=metabolites)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 7
  metabolites    A1    A2    A3    B1    B2    B3
  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 m1           3.70  1.42  3.39  1.48  2.61 0.600
2 m2           0     4.11  2.66  1.52  2.69 0.314
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(metabolites = c("m1", "m2", "m3"), A1 = c(3.703345, 
0, 0), A2 = c(1.417572, 4.114684, 1.196729), A3 = c(3.388284, 
2.659948, 1.37332), B1 = c(1.480509, 1.517864, 0), B2 = c(2.612082, 
2.690435, 3.943517), B3 = c(0.5997665, 0.3141896, 1.8687265)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I like your solution because I can now generalize this to my actual data with 100s of columns and column groups.

Comment: For some reason your code does not work if I use any(value > 0) instead of == 0. If I use > then it returns TRUE for all rows. Do you have any idea how to edit it so that I can generalize the condition in this line?

Comment: @Mikki  Right now it checks if there's a zero in a group and labels the whole group TRUE (through `any`). If you do `> 0` it looks if it finds a single value greater zero and labels the whole group TRUE. What's your new goal?

Comment: thanks for your rapid reply. My goal new goal is to use this code to filter out metabolites that don't have values greater than 10 000 in at least one group. So I want this code to work with >0 here or >1 etc., though am struggling to reformat it accordingly. I wanted to compare that to filtering out metabolites with non-zeros though and so initially posed the question asking to filter metabolites without complete non-zeros in at least one group.

Comment: Actually, it seems to be doing the correct thing if I swop the first any for all and the all for any. So now: df_filtered <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-metabolites) %>% 
  mutate(grp = sub("\\d+$", "", name)) %>% 
  mutate(any_zero = all(value > 0), .by = c(metabolites, grp)) %>% 
  filter(any(any_zero), .by = metabolites) %>% 
  select(-c(grp, any_zero)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols=metabolites)

Comment: @Mikki It seems you now want `... any(value <= 1)` and `filter(all(any_zero)`

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

I think you were on right track by bringing the dataframe in long format. You can try this.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_long <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -metabolites, names_pattern = "([A-Z])(\\d)", 
               names_to = c('group', 'replicates'))

df_long %>%
  summarise(res = as.integer(any(value > 0)), 
           .by = c(metabolites, replicates)) %>%
  group_by(metabolites) %>%
  filter(all(res > 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-res) %>%
  left_join(df_long, by = join_by(metabolites, replicates)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(group, replicates), 
              values_from = value, names_sep = "", names_sort = TRUE)

# metabolites    A1    A2    A3    B1    B2    B3
#  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 m1           2.38  2.63  2.01  2.99  2.01  4.86
#2 m2           0     1.35  3.67  3.96  3.09  2.07
```

Comment: Thank for your response! X